# How to avoid hardcoding contract address in Solidity

Tags: solidity

When looking at other team's smart contracts, I often see code like this:

```
address constant public token = address(0xabc123...);
```

Where the hexadecimal number is the address of an earlier-deployed smart contract. Coming from JS and C++ background, I'm not a fan of this because it effectively hardcodes what should be in a configuration file directly into the smart contract code. Several questions come to mind when I see code like this:

- What if I want to deploy this to another EVM-compatible network?
- What if I want to deploy this to testnet?

I'm still relatively new to Solidity, so it's possible I'm missing some feature of truffle that allows me to insert these strings at the time of deployment, but I didn't see this mentioned in any of the tutorials I went through. I would much rather have something like a JSON configuration file for testnet/mainnet/L2-chain/etc instead of having N versions of the same file with minor differences. How should I handle these cases?

Comment: the contract address is not change

Comment: @MERN, imagine deploying the app on Ethereum, pointing to ETH's address somewhere in the code, and then perhaps WETH address as well. Now let's say a few months later you also decide to deploy your app to BSC. All ETH references now need to point to BNB, all WETH references need to point to WBNB. The addresses are clearly not the same, and this use case of referencing the underlying platform token or an earlier-deployed contract (i.e. platform's main DEX, for example), is quite common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a variable (instead of a constant) containing the `token` address. And this variable can be set from a constructor.

So you can effectively pass the value from an environment variable to the contract constructor, to the contract storage.

---

Example:

*.env*

```
TOKEN_ADDRESS=0x123
```

*deploy.js* using Truffle ([docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#-code-mycontract-new-arg1-arg2-tx-params-code-)) for example

```
MyContract.new(process.env.TOKEN_ADDRESS)
```

You can also use Hardhat ([docs](https://hardhat.org/config/#networks-configuration)) or any other library allowing you to deploy to any network depending on the config.

*MyContract.sol*

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    address token;

    constructor(address _token) {
        token = _token;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, passing the address via constructor via truffle deploy makes sense.